# Trackpoint and touchpad Lenovo L460 Thinkpad (15.10)

Tags: touchpad, thinkpad, trackpoint

on my L460 thinkpad neither the trackpoint nor the trackpad work. I am only able to use the gui with an external mouse connected.

I tried with the kernels 4.5 rc 4, 4.5 rc 6, 4.2.0 16 and 4.2.0 30.

Am I missing something I can do about it? Will try latest 4.4 kernel in a few.

(latest synaptics package is installed and the xinput list is not showing a pointing device)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: no trackpoint or touchpad on 4.4.2 either

Comment: On both of my Lenovos, the trackpad can be enabled and disabled in the BIOS. How about yours?

Comment: thank you, I did not check that but as the trackpad and touchpoint were fine in windows 7  I suppose they are enabled. b4shyou provided an answer I wasn't hoping for but works as a workaround. On the other hand I am not able now to troubleshoot with the kernel...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem

Get yourself a windows installation usb stick and then start installing windows.
The first screen lets you choose your language.
There you can check if the touchpad works. Just move the mouse a little. Then halt and start installing ubuntu.
Now it worked for me

I hope that works for you too =)
Greets

Comment: yes, thank you. it worked somehow. This was not the solution I was hoping for but at least the laptop is usable on the go. Do you have any good xorg.conf.d files to make the trackpoint more usable?

Comment: nice to hear that
Unfortunately, I dont have any xorg confs atm

Comment: Did you know: as soon as you plug the power by pulling the battery the trackpoint and touchpad support is gone again.. will try later if I am able to revive with antoher go on the windows usb stick..

Answer (score 3):

Modifying the file `/etc/default/grub` and inserting `i8042.reset` in the quote on the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. Then save your modification and start `sudo update-grub`. It should work.

Comment: This works! May I ask what is i8042.reset actually doing?

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
$ synclient TouchPadOff=0
```

worked. I'm not yet sure, whether it is necessary to add this to `~/.profile` as described in my source http://thinkwiki.de/Debian_Schnelleinstieg#Touchpad_deaktivieren (german).

Comment: Configuring hardware that's not detected is unlikely to work.