# Touchpad not detected on Thinkpad T530

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, thinkpad

Touchpad does not seem to be detected on recently purchased refurbished Lenovo Thinkpad T530.  Running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.  Touchpad works fine on Windows on internal hard drive.  Also, it does work on Ubuntu 17.04.

You can see that running xinput list there is a USB mouse detected but not a touchpad:

```
*********:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Optical Mouse                id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera                         id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Tried answer here, didn't work: [Thinkpad E460 touchpad not detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/743267/thinkpad-e460-touchpad-not-detected)

Tried the second answer here, didn't work: [Trackpoint and touchpad Lenovo L460 Thinkpad (15.10)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/740556/trackpoint-and-touchpad-lenovo-l460-thinkpad-15-10)

Tried to run the answer here, didn't get it to run: [Touchpad not detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/469746/touchpad-not-detected)

Please let me know if you can help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since this does work on Ubuntu 17.04 it seems it may be a kernel issue.  See the response below...

Comment: This implies the problem is something in a configuration. Your issue is still open, I'd say. Please [edit] this answer into your original question and someone might be able to help you actually solve this problem for good.

Comment: This is a kernel issue. It IS actually solved. Another way was to install kernel 4.10 to Ubuntu 16.04.